# Debug C/C++ application on linux through Eclipse

Tags: c++, c, linux, eclipse, debugging

I am working on a C/C++ reverse engineering project, which requires some debugging to get precise understanding of the logic in C. All post related to this subject is fairly old, the latest at 2015. Now it is end of 2019, many things changed. So I am putting up the solution for the time.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right place for this. Stack Overflow isn't an online note-keeping app. Did you publicly post something that should have gone to teams?

Comment: I am sure it is. Someone already upvoted it.

Answer (score -1):

The first thing I tried is remote debugging from windows eclipse. C/C++ code runs on linux box using command "gdbserver localhost:2345 cprocess". The obstacle I faced was that gdbclient on windows eclipse side (from mingW installation) is at 8.2, yet server side gdbserver is at 8.3. Too much issue while trying to fix it.

Next thing I tried is to launch eclipse from linux and it worked. Steps below:

1. download the package and install on linux. https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/file/39888.
   unzip it: "tar -xvzf eclipse-linuxtools-helios-SR2-incubation-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz". Incubation 
   package has lots of dependency packaged within. Other packages require dependency to resolve.
2. install x11 related and x-forwarding. Eclipse runs on linux. For UI to popup, it requires windows component. This component listens to data forwarded from linux and display. I referred to this article 
   https://www.osradar.com/configure-x11-forwarding-in-centos-rhel-6-7-8-and-fedora-28-29/

   (a) install xming at https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/
   (b) on linux box install xorg-x11-server-Xorg xorg-x11-xauth xorg-x11-apps.
       To find the exact version to install, do a "yum list | grep -i xorg". Then "sudo yum install the-right-version-components"
   (c) open putty with X11 option checked.
   [image]

   (d) type "eclipse" on your linux box and Eclipse should startup on your windows.

PS, the eclipse incubation package in in java6, I could not find java8 version that can be installed on linux easily. So you may need to install java6 and set env.

```
    export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45  
    export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

3. Launch you app in linux, use eclipse c/c++ "Attache to Application".

[image]